# Storing each digit of a number into separate variables

Tags: python, sorting

for example i have this variable:

```
x=123
```

how can i convert it to a tuple or each digit into separate variables?:

```
x=(1,2,3)
```

or

```
x1=1
x2=2
x3=3
```

Comment: Do you always know how many digits the number has?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
>>> x=123
>>> tuple(map(int, str(x)))
(1, 2, 3)
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use a comprehension with a tuple after casting the value to a string:

```
x=123
x = tuple(int(i) for i in str(x))
```

Output:

```
(1, 2, 3)
```

Answer (score 1):

Convert to a string, convert each digit to an int, then unpack directly into variables:

```
x = 123
x1, x2, x3 = [int(i) for i in str(x)]
```

This requires that you know in advance how many digits are present in the string. Better to just use a tuple or list to hold the digits and reference them by index.

```
t = tuple(int(i) for i in str(x))
t[0]
# 1
etc.
```

Comment: I think they want ints.

Comment: @ᴡʜᴀᴄᴋᴀᴍᴀᴅᴏᴏᴅʟᴇ3000: thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Code:

```
    x = 1234567
    digits = []

    print("number: " + str(x))

    while x > 0:
        digits.append(x % 10)
        x = int(x / 10)

    # To put it back in order
    digits.reverse()

    for i in range(len(digits)):
        print(digits[i])
```

Output:

```
number: 1234567
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
```